# How to execute code returned from a JSON string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have code with html and javascript stored in a JSON string. I'd like to return this on a page but instead of returning it as a string, I'd like the html and javascript to be executed on page in my react app as if hard coded.

Right now it's returning the code as a string.

Ive tried eval(), JSON.parse, and dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but I don't only have HTML in the string, there are also javascript template literals and scoped css classes.

I left the code below but also created a demo at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dynamic-javascript-from-json-s42dse?file=/components/Helloworld.js)

json file (encoded)

```
{
  "code": {
    "html": "<div className={styles.container}>\r\n. <h1 className={`${styles.red} ${styles.big}`}>Hello World</h1>\r\n. </div>"
  }
}
```

JS page

```
import Helloworld from "../components/Helloworld";
import componentCode from "../data/data";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Helloworld displaycode={componentCode} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

JS Component

```
import styles from "./Helloworld.module.scss";
export default function HelloWorld(props) {
  let htmlCode = props.displaycode.code.html;
  return (
    <>
      {htmlCode}
      {/* This code stored in the string should execute like below */}
      {/* <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1 className={`${styles.red} ${styles.big}`}>Hello World</h1>
      </div> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import styles from "./Helloworld.module.scss";
export default function HelloWorld(props) {
  let htmlCode = props.displaycode.code.html;
  return (
    <>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlCode }}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I did it this way and it is working
I have referenced from :
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: I have tried this, but if you test this you will see the CSS class names and template literals aren't executing - only the HTML, but I appreciate your response.

Comment: my guess is className is what you add yourself to the JSON data, instead why don't you use `style inline` like this style='color: red;' . you can write a format string to add the corresponding style to the text.

example response: <code><div className={styles.container}>\r\n      <h1 style='color: red;'>Hello World</h1>\r\n    </div></code>

Comment: Because this is just a demo but generally the components have a lot css styles and used scoped css so they stay within the component. I would’ve love to get this to work.